# Are these sentences correct?

Tags: meaning, word

大家好！

1.大女方四岁。
2.男方大四岁。
3.男方大其四岁。

Are these sentences correct?

谢谢！

有大神回答下吗？

Answer (score 1):

Understandable but incorrect grammar-wise.

1."男方"大女方四岁。 2.男方"比女方"大四岁。 3."所以"男方大其四岁。

The original: 1.大女方四岁。 2.男方大四岁。 3.男方大其四岁。

In the original, the first sentence with 主詞 (男方) missing. The second sentence has to add 比較格(比) and 受詞(女方) to make sense, and the third sentence needs 聯結[連接]詞(所以) to make the paragraph complete.

Answer (score 0):

They are all correct sentences.

As answered by r13, these sentences contain omission of subject and object for the 1st and 2nd sentences, respectively. But they are still correct and don't sound weird either, because normal people would certainly understand their context is about a relationship.